# Pandas: Split data frame based on empty rows

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have the following data frame.

```
id       A        B        C   
1      34353    917998     x        
2      34973    980340     x      
3      87365    498097     x      
4      98309    486547     x      
5      87699    475132         
6      52734    4298894         
7      8749267  4918066    x    
8      89872    18103         
9      589892   4818086    y    
10     765      4063       y 
11     32369    418165     y
12     206      2918137    
13     554      3918072    
14     1029     1918051    x
15     2349243  4918064
```

For each set of the empty rows e.g. 5,6 I want to create a new data frame. It is required to produce multiple data frames. As given below:

```
id      A        B
5      87699    475132         
6      52734    4298894
```

```
id      A        B
8      89872    18103
```

```
id      A        B
12     206      2918137    
13     554      3918072
```

```
id      A        B
15     2349243  4918064
```

Comment: please post desired data set(s), because it's not clear whether you want to have one or multiple data sets...

Comment: And how do you want to name the new DF's?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
isnull = df.C.isnull()
partitions = (isnull != isnull.shift()).cumsum()

gb = df[isnull].groupby(partitions)
```

At this point, we've accomplished the goal in creating a separate dataframe for each contiguous group of `NaN` in `df`.  They are accessible via the `gb.get_group()` method for each key in `gb.groups`

To verify, we will concatenate display.

```
keys = gb.groups.keys()
dfs = pd.concat([gb.get_group(g) for g in keys], keys=keys)
dfs
```

[image]

#### Setup for `df`

I used @Alberto Garcia-Raboso's reader

```
import io
import pandas as pd

# Create your sample dataframe
data = io.StringIO("""\
id       A        B        C   
1      34353    917998     x        
2      34973    980340     x      
3      87365    498097     x      
4      98309    486547     x      
5      87699    475132         
6      52734    4298894         
7      8749267  4918066    x    
8      89872    18103         
9      589892   4818086    y    
10     765      4063       y 
11     32369    418165     y
12     206      2918137    
13     554      3918072    
14     1029     1918051    x
15     2349243  4918064
""")
df = pd.read_csv(data, delim_whitespace=True)
```

Comment: I like your solution looks much more compared  to mine!

Comment: Very elegant indeed!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
x = df[pd.isnull(df.C)]

splitter = x.reset_index()[(x['id'].diff().fillna(0) > 1).reset_index(drop=True)].index

dfs = np.split(x, splitter)

for x in dfs:
    print(x, '\n')
```

Output:

```
In [264]: for x in l:
   .....:         print(x, '\n')
   .....:
   id      A        B    C
4   5  87699   475132  NaN
5   6  52734  4298894  NaN

   id      A      B    C
7   8  89872  18103  NaN

    id    A        B    C
11  12  206  2918137  NaN
12  13  554  3918072  NaN

    id        A        B    C
14  15  2349243  4918064  NaN
```

Explanation:

```
In [267]: x = df[pd.isnull(df.C)]

In [268]: x
Out[268]:
    id        A        B    C
4    5    87699   475132  NaN
5    6    52734  4298894  NaN
7    8    89872    18103  NaN
11  12      206  2918137  NaN
12  13      554  3918072  NaN
14  15  2349243  4918064  NaN

In [269]: x.ix[pd.isnull(df.C), 'id']
Out[269]:
4      5
5      6
7      8
11    12
12    13
14    15
Name: id, dtype: int64

In [270]: x['id'].diff().fillna(0)
Out[270]:
4     0.0
5     1.0
7     2.0
11    4.0
12    1.0
14    2.0
Name: id, dtype: float64

In [271]: x['id'].diff().fillna(0) > 1
Out[271]:
4     False
5     False
7      True
11     True
12    False
14     True
Name: id, dtype: bool

In [272]: (x['id'].diff().fillna(0) > 1).reset_index(drop=True)
Out[272]:
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
5     True
Name: id, dtype: bool

In [273]: x.reset_index()[x['id'].diff().fillna(0) > 1).reset_index(drop=True)]
Out[273]:
   index  id        A        B    C
2      7   8    89872    18103  NaN
3     11  12      206  2918137  NaN
5     14  15  2349243  4918064  NaN

In [274]: x.reset_index()[(x['id'].diff().fillna(0) > 1).reset_index(drop=True)].index
Out[274]: Int64Index([2, 3, 5], dtype='int64')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly convoluted, probably not very fast solution using `itertools.groupby` (which famously lumps together sequences of consecutive like values).

```
from itertools import groupby
import io

import pandas as pd

# Create your sample dataframe
data = io.StringIO("""\
id       A        B        C   
1      34353    917998     x        
2      34973    980340     x      
3      87365    498097     x      
4      98309    486547     x      
5      87699    475132         
6      52734    4298894         
7      8749267  4918066    x    
8      89872    18103         
9      589892   4818086    y    
10     765      4063       y 
11     32369    418165     y
12     206      2918137    
13     554      3918072    
14     1029     1918051    x
15     2349243  4918064
""")
df = pd.read_csv(data, delim_whitespace=True)

# Create a boolean column that encodes which rows you want to keep
df['grouper'] = df['C'].notnull()

# Isolate the indices of the rows you want to keep, grouped by contiguity
groups = [list(map(lambda x: x[1]['id'], list(l)))
              for k, l in groupby(df.iterrows(), key=lambda x: x[1]['grouper'])
              if not k]
print(groups)     # => [[5, 6], [8], [12, 13], [15]]

# Gather the sub-dataframes whose indices match `groups`
dfs = []
for g in groups:
    dfs.append(df[['A', 'B']][df['id'].isin(g)])

# Inspect what you got
for df in dfs:
    print(df)
```

Output:

```
       A        B
4  87699   475132
5  52734  4298894
       A      B
7  89872  18103
      A        B
11  206  2918137
12  554  3918072
          A        B
14  2349243  4918064
```